# Load dijit widgets before iframe images

Tags: java, javascript, image, dojo

I have a page that uses several dijit form widgets.  I also have an iframe on each side of my form that display various ads.

I noticed that certain ads take a while to load and that my dijit widgets do not render until the page is ready because my code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.dijit");
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
    dojo.require("dijit.TitlePane");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.CheckBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.RadioButton");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
    dojo.require("dijit.Tooltip");

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {     
    dojo.addOnLoad(myFunction);
});
```

Is there a way I can make my dijit widgets that are on my form render first and then the ads display after?  I know I can probably use ajax to get the ads after the page is ready but I was wondering if there was a different solution?

Thanks

Comment: There is quite a lot of ways. I don't quite know how you are loading your Advertisments, because you could easily change how you load the advertisements. You could also ask yourself do you strictly need an iframe to load the ads? Is this from an external service? Because then I would be tempted to use dojo.io and dojo.deferrered using a addCallback to load the IFRAME.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will look into those functions today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using dojo.xhrGet to get my ads after the page loaded like this:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  getAds();
});
```

Inside getAds() it just does a simple xhrGet.